# How can I get value instead of id in gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin

Query:- `g .V(). has Label('Attribute').as_('a').in_('has').as_('b').in_('purchased').as_('c').select('a' ,'b' ,'c').group Count().by('a').order(Scope .local).by(Column .values , Order . DESC ).to List()`

Output:-`[{v[col1]: 6,v[s4]: 4,v[col2]: 3,v[s2]: 3,v[s3]: 2,v[pat1]: 2,v[pat2]: 2,v[col3]: 2,v[s1]: 2,v[pat3]: 1}]`

So I want to ask that how can I get the value instead of id?(eg-I want to get col1-Red)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `by()` modulator to `select()` to transform the `Vertex` to a value. Here I assume that you want the "color" (as your example suggested that the output would be "Red"):

```
g.V(). hasLabel('Attribute').as_('a').
  in_('has').as_('b').
  in_('purchased').as_('c').
  select('a' ,'b' ,'c').
    by('color').
  groupCount().by('a').
  order(Scope .local).
    by(Column .values , Order . DESC)
```

That `by()` would be applied in round-robin fashion to "a", "b" and "c" so, if those didn't have a "color" property key or if you wanted a different property for each of those keys you would add a `by()` specific to "b" and "c".